# Delete zero rows in a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, matrix

If there is a matrix with some of its rows equal to zero: (its zero rows are randomly distributed and does not have an ordered arrangement): same as:

```
m={{1,2,I},{0,0,0},{I,I,3},{2,6,I},{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{1,6,4},{0,0,0},{1,4,5}}
```

How can I have a mm matrix without any zero rows and all its rows are m's rows

```
mm={{1,2,I},{I,I,3},{2,6,I},{1,6,4},{1,4,5}}
```

Comment: `Cases[m, Except@{0 ..}]` seems the most natural way to me, but probably not the most efficient

Comment: I expect some variation of `Select[m, Norm[#] > 0&]` to perform better but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Both of them work well.

Comment: `DeleteCases[m, {0 ..}]` should work.

Comment: `m /. {0 ..} -> Sequence[]`

Comment: @Algohi, I believe the new version has `Nothing` you can use…

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use:

```
Select[m,#!={0,0,0}&]
```

Where #!={0,0,0}& is a pure function that returns True for any list not equal to the list of three 0's.

Comment: In which case, you should accept it by clicking the tick-mark next to the upvote arrows.

Comment: Yes, I know for accepting an answer, but I have heard not soon accepting an answer. Because of existing a time to others for present their answers.

Comment: @JohMcGee - A more general form using `Select` would be `Select[m, FreeQ[#, {0 ..}] &]`

Answer (score 9):

This s/b considerably faster for large cases:

```
#[[Union[SparseArray[#]["NonzeroPositions"][[All, 1]]]]] &@array
```

and this is even faster:

```
Replace[#, ConstantArray[0, Length@#[[1]]] -> Sequence[], {1}] &@array
```

and about the same as latter:

```
DeleteCases[#, ConstantArray[0, Length@#[[1]]]]&@array
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
m = {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
0}, {1, 6, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 4, 5}};

DeleteCases[m, {0 ..}, Infinity]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 2 & i \\
>  i & i & 3 \\
>  2 & 6 & i \\
>  1 & 6 & 4 \\
>  1 & 4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 6):

A method that should go well with purely numerical matrices (at least when `m` has significantly fewer columns than rows) is

```
Pick[m, Unitize[Abs[m].ConstantArray[1., cols]], 1]
```

It vectorizes the row checks and does not unpack `PackedArray`s.

Answer (score 4):

```
Delete[m, Position[m, ConstantArray[0, Length[First[m]]], {1}]]
```

Or just

```
Delete[m, Position[m, {0 ..}, {1}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m = {{1, 2, I}, {0}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 6, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 4, 5}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Join @@ SequenceSplit[m, {{0 ..}}]
```

{{1, 2, I}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {1, 6, 4}, {1, 4, 5}}

Answer (score 3):

Using `ReplaceAll` and `ContainsOnly`:

```
m = {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, I, 3},
    {2, 6, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, 
    {1, 6, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 4, 5}};
mm = {{1, 2, I}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {1, 6, 4}, {1, 4, 5}};

(m /. x_List /; ContainsOnly[x, {0}] :> Nothing) === mm

(*True*)
```

Or using `ZeroArrayQ`:

```
(m /. x_ /; LinearAlgebra`Private`ZeroArrayQ[x] :> Nothing) === mm

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 3):

I am adding some contributions. As far as I checked there's no overlap with the suggestions so far. If someone spots something, I would appreciate a comment and I will remove the duplicate.

I am grabbing from @E. Chan-López

```
m = {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0}, {1, 6, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 4, 5}};
mm = {{1, 2, I}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {1, 6, 4}, {1, 4, 5}};
```

All of the following return `True`

```
DeleteElements[m, {0 ..} :> Infinity];
mm === %
m //. {0 ..} :> Unevaluated[## &[]];
mm === %
m //. {0 ..} -> Sequence[];
mm === %
m //. {0 ..} :> Nothing;
mm === %
Delete[Position[{0 ..}]@m]@m;
mm === %
Select[#, UnequalTo[0]] & /@ m //. {} :> Nothing;
mm === %
Cases[m, Except@{0 ..}];
mm === %
Select[m, x |-> FreeQ[x, {0 ..}]];
mm == %
Pick[m, Total /@ Unitize@m, Except[0 | _List]]
mm == %
```

**Edit** I am adding this variant which was suggested by the fellow 10-fold ways @ E. Chan-López in the comments

```
Pick[m, ! MatchQ[#, {0 ..}] & /@ m]
```

Comment: An alternative using `Pick`: `Pick[m, ! MatchQ[#, {0 ..}] & /@ m]` :-)

Comment: @E.Chan-López thanks a lot mate :-) Updated

Answer (score 1):

**Using `DiscreteDelta`:**

```
m = {{1, 2, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
    0}, {1, 6, 4}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 4, 5}};

Pick[m, DiscreteDelta @@@ m, 0]
```

or

```
Select[EqualTo[0]@*Apply[DiscreteDelta]][m]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 2, I}, {I, I, 3}, {2, 6, I}, {1, 6, 4}, {1, 4, 5}}

Comment: +1 - I didn't even know this function :)

Comment: Also explore the `KroneckerDelta`. @eldo

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to delete cases where a certain column is zero, say the last column, this works:

```
Select[m,#!={#,#,0}&]
```

Comment: First of all, this is not the point in this topic, you can find an appropriate one and add the answer there. Secondly, this is very hairy, such function `# != {#, #, 0} &@{1, 1, 0}` is left unevaluated.